# How can I define a custom BadRequest html page in ASP.NET Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have razor page and handler method that can possibly return `BadRequestObjectResult` as an response.

```
public class ConfirmEmailModel : PageModel {

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string payload) {
  if (validatePayload(payload)) 
  {
      return BadRequest("Your request was badly formatted.");
  }
  return Page();
}
```

When I return `BadRequest` the browser gets `Status Code: 400` and shows string `Your request was badly formatted.` as ordinary text without any HTML formatting (response header contains `content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`).

Is there a way to provide response with full HTML page (eg. string passed in `BadRequest` can be wrapped in say `<h2>` or something like that) when I return bad request response?

Answer (score 0):

in your case i suggest to create a razor page for badrequest which takes a message
then redirect to it (you can handle it inside that get page too using if condition)

```
return Redirect("/BadRequest?error=Your request was badly formatted");
```

then handle the mesage inside that page like this

```
        [BindProperty]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
            return Page();
        }
```

in html page

```
<h1>@Model.Message</h1>
```

if you really need your message contains html, you can use it like this inside html page

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Message)
```

your redirect be like :

```
return Redirect("/BadRequest?error=<h1>Your request was badly formatted</h1>");
```